# Linear Regression statsmodel: Missing a required outcome variable

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am using `statsmodel` to build a linear regression for salary. It's giving me an error that says I am  missing a required outcome variable. Can you tell what I am doing wrong here? My initial model, `my_model` seemed working but the `ols` fitted model says I am missing a required outcome variable.

```
my_model = str('Salary ~  X1 + X2')`
my_model = str('')

train_model_fit = smf.ols(my_model, data = X_train).fit()

print(train_model_fit.summary())
X_train['predict_salary'] = train_model_fit.fittedvalues
X_test['predict_salary'] = train_model_fit.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: your formola `my_model` is an empty string

Comment: lol i missed it, thanks!

Comment: happens to the best of us :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Answering for completeness]

You set the model formula in the first line:

```
my_model = str('Salary ~  X1 + X2')`
```

But then you assign an empty string to it:

```
my_model = str('')
```

Hence the error.